# WebServlet list for logged users

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, notserializableexception

I'm trying to create a list of medicines so that the user who added the medicines could see them and only him and that he wouldn't see the medicines of other users. But when I log in on accout which have 2 medicines added to databese and I visit my servlet /mlist i see "No drugs on the list" because to my user_id is assigned 0 and i don't get it why.

//edit
"My `request.getSession().getAttribute("user_id");` was wrong because it didn't take the user session, correct is `request.getSession().getAttribute("user");` "

But now i got new problem `PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT id_medicines, name, drugform, quantity, expiration_date, description, user_id FROM medicines WHERE user_id= ?Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException`
//

SQL call

```
public List<Medicines> findByProperty(String propName, Object propValue) {
        String sql = "SELECT id_medicines, name, drugform, quantity, expiration_date, 
        description, user_id FROM medicines WHERE "+propName+"= ?";
        List<Medicines> medicines = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new MedicinesRowMapper(), propValue);
        return medicines;
    }
```

Medicines Service

```
public List<Medicines> findUserMedicines(User user_id){
        DAOFactory factory = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory();
        MedicinesDAO medicinesDao = factory.getMedicinesDAO();
        return medicinesDao.findByProperty("user_id", user_id);
    }`
```

findUserMedicines taking from DAOFactory this line `public abstract MedicinesDAO getMedicinesDAO();`

Servlet /mlist

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
             {
        medicinesList(request);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/mlist.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    public void medicinesList(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        MedicinesService medicinesService = new MedicinesService();
        User user_id = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        List<Medicines> userMedicines =  medicinesService.findUserMedicines(user_id);
        request.setAttribute("medicines", userMedicines);
    }
```

LoginFilter

```
private void saveUserInSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    String username = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    User userByUsername = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
    request.getSession(true).setAttribute("user", userByUsername);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line `User user_id = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");`. Your `User` class which you have not provided in your question is not serialized. But even if you would make it serializable I doubt it would give you the result you want.

I suppose your user id is actually a `String`. Get the user id from your `User` object as a `String` and pass that along in your query instead. (The same could apply even if it where an `int`or a `long`. You need to get it from your `User` object.

Something similar to

```
String userIdString = user_id.getId();
```

I can update the answer if you provide your `User` class in the question.

Comment: But im taking that session from my LoginFilter.java. Look first post I had added that code.It's taking user by String username, it is a problem, ye?

Comment: You are missing the point a bit. The exception you are getting is because you are passing the entire `User` object into your query, while you probably only should pass along the actual user name in String format. Having a `User` object in the session is not the problem. You must be able to get the user name from the `User`object somehow.

Comment: Alright it's already done, the problem was `return medicinesDao.findByProperty("user_id", user_id);` correctly it's look like this `return medicinesDao.findByProperty("user_id", user_id.getId());` Really big thanks for help.